# Probability of head occurring for first k times followed by a tail, if a coin is tossed n times

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-distribution

In a fair coin toss, what is the probability that head occurs k times followed by a tail, i.e a tail in k+1 trail, if we toss a coin n times ?

Also, if we modify the question by asking for the probability where an outcome starts with an even number of head, followed by a tail, how do I get the general formula for this?

Comment: Hint: it will be equal to the probability of getting heads $k+1$ times.

Comment: Oh, because the probability for head and tail is same, we can say it equals to head occurring k+1 times. Thanks. Do you also have hint for second question?

Comment: I don't see anything different on the second question.  I don't see why it matters that it is an even number of heads.

Comment: Because it's not a fixed number, it can be any even number

Answer (score 0):

1 should be obvious from the comments.

It is equal to  the probability of any one of these:

T, HHT, HHHHT, HHHHHHT, ...

These are mutually exclusive events, and if the coin in unbiased, the probability is

$\ \ \ \frac 1 2 + \frac1 2 \cdot\frac 1 2 \cdot \frac1 2  + \frac1 2 \cdot\frac 1 2 \cdot \frac1 2  \cdot \frac 1 2 \cdot \frac 1 2 \ \  + \cdot\cdot\cdot $

= 
$\frac 1 2 (1+ \frac1 {2^2} + \frac 1 {2^4} + \frac1 {2^6}  +  \cdot\cdot\cdot )$

= 
$\frac 1 2 \cdot \frac 1 {1-\frac 1 {2^2}} $

= $\frac 2 3$

Comment: Can you please explain me the process leading to (1 - (1/2^2). Thanks

Comment: $\frac 1 {1- a} = 1+a+ a^2+a^3+ ... $
as long as $|a|<0$

Comment: ... should be $|a| < 1$. Here $a=\frac 1 {2^2}$. Sorry noticed it late.